# Button's ControlTemplate's ContentPresenter's Textblock's Foreground not changing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

I have tried the following...

1. Setting the button's TextBlock.Foreground.
2. Setting the contentpresenter's TextBlock.Foreground.
3. Setting the IsMouseOver Trigger as it is shown here.
4. Setting the IsMouseOver Trigger without a target name (assuming it hits the button).
5. Everywhere I have tried TextBlock.Foreground, I have tried TextElement.Foreground.

What am I missing!? I am assuming there is some minor oversight I have made. (It is not my code, but it is now my responsibility :\

Also, be aware of this fact, the places where this style is used, the button's command and content are bound to a mvvm style view model.

```
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="border" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Color2}"/>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" TextElement.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource ButtonIsFocusedBackgroundBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true"/>



                    <!---HERE IS THE PROBLEM (note: the background works fine)--->
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource ButtonHoverOverBackgroundBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    <!---HERE IS THE PROBLEM--->


                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#FF8B7A54"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.33"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 9):

Ok, I finally figured it out. I slept on it and realized that I have a default textblock style defined elsewhere in my application. It was getting applied to the contentpresenter textblock property. Somehow (I am not sure how if someone wants to comment on it) this style was blocking the trigger from working properly. So here is the solution -> I am only posting the edited content presenter...

```
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 

                                      TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                      TextElement.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                      Focusable="False" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{x:Null}" />
                        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                    </ContentPresenter>
```

By clearing the textblock style, the trigger works. I would like to know why this is though.