# WPF Button ControlTemplate won't override Inherited Foreground

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

My global (`App.xaml`) ControlTemplate for `Button` doesn't want to override the `Foreground` property from its default black colouring. This seems to be a relatively common problem, but I've tried various solutions including setting the `BasedOn` to `null` as [described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115169/buttons-controltemplates-contentpresenters-textblocks-foreground-not-changin).

My code is below, and you can see I've tried to explicitly state the foreground colour on both the `Grid` and the `ContentPresenter`. Yet the colour stays black. Snoop tells me it's inherited as default, though doesn't seem to say from where, and shows the parent `ContentPresenter` as having `TextElement.Foreground` set to the correct colour.

Is there something in this code that I should be setting? Have I missed an element or property?

```cs
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="grid" TextBlock.Foreground="#FFD3D3D2">
                    <Border x:Name="border" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="#FF5C7999" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=ActualHeight,Converter={StaticResource HalfConverter}}" Padding="10">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0" TextBlock.Foreground="#FFD3D3D2">
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
...
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue based on what you've got there. What context is the button appearing in? What are you using for `Content`?

Comment: Actually, I *can* reproduce it: `<Button Content="Foo" />` gets me a gray "Foo". `<Button><Label>Foo</Label></Button>` gets me a black "Foo".

Comment: I can put an implicit `Style` for `Label` in `ControlTemplate.Resources`, which will apply to the `Label` content.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I only saw your first answer and set off to check the content. See my posted answer - that did it. However, I'll happily accept an answer from you explaining the above, if you'd like.

Comment: Yep, that's where I was going with that question. We probably tested it simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the buttons using this style were setting their content to things other than text, or explicitly adding a style-less `TextBlock` inside, and this was overriding anything set by the `Foreground` attributes in the original code.

Ensuring that *only* text was set as the button contents, or ensuring that the wrappers thereof were styled appropriately, fixed the problem.

It seems that rubber duck debugging works after all.

Answer (score 1):

Testing this, your `Style` works as you expect if `Button.Content` is a string, but not if it's a control:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Gray Text As Specified in the ControlTemplate" />
    <Button><Label>Default Black Text</Label></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

I can add an implicit `Label` style to `ControlTemplate.Resources` which overrides the `Label`'s `Foreground`, but it would be ridiculous to try to have local implicit styles for every possible control somebody could put in there.

But if you just stick with plain strings for the `Content`, it'll work. Now I'm going to spend some time researching [the inheritance rules for attached properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197(v=vs.110).aspx), because I think I'm about 51% semi-confident that this isn't the behavior I'd usually want.

Comment: Thanks Ed. Upvoted if not only for the "51% semi-confident"-ness.